# How animate path in WAAPI?

Tags: javascript, svg, web-animations, ecma

How (if at all) can I animate `d` in web animation? In the example `stroke` and `strokeWidth` are working, `d` doesn't?!

```
<svg id="svg-path-anim" width="60" height="50"  style="border:1px solid #00f"> 
<path id="wave1" d="M10,10L50,10" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />

<script type="text/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[
var wave1 =   document.getElementById("wave1");
var playerWave1=wave1.animate([
{stroke:'#00f', strokeWidth:1, d:'M10,10,L50,10'},
{stroke:'#f00', strokeWidth:4, d:'M10,10,L50,40'}],
{duration:3000, delay:0,iterations: Infinity});
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

EDIT: Any **preferred alternatives**  of achieving scripted path animation (without SMIL)?

Comment: I don't think any UA supports d animation yet.

Comment: what a shame, considering SMIL did that easily!

Comment: SMIL has been around for years, the web animation spec is still being written as is SVG 2. You would have hand similar problems with SMIL when the spec was in draft.